# Implement OpenId Connect on existing servlet web application

Tags: tomcat, servlets, google-openid, openid-connect

I have a simple java servlet app running on tomcat8. All it does is search and return the json response. Now I want to implement OpenId connect to this servlet app. My goal is to let user authenticate when they hit the search button but to get hold on OpenId connect I want to implement login feature first using OpenId connect.

My application running on tomcat port 80. Send a request to port 8080 on search. For example for searching users request goes to `https://localhost:8080/api/vi/username=johnDoe`

I am new to this OpenId connect concept and also fairly new to servlet. There is lot documentation and I am not sure what approach should I take. 
**1. Implicit or 2. server flow.**

For implicit I was thinking when user do search client will ask for authentication and on authenticate let user do search and return response.

But I am very confused about server flow. How server flow works in my case? Can anyone explain?

Using this `https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/java` as quick start.

Thanks